# Create_program_address vs find_program_address

Tags: anchor, address, pubkey

In the Rust crate, there are `create_program_address` and `find_program_address`. When using Anchor, I have seen both of them being used for doing address matching.

Noticeably, `find_program_address` does not use the `bump` for recreating the address, whereas `create_program_address` takes the `bump` as input.

So I was wondering if I should be using one over the other for address matching/checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When checking if some account matches an expected derived PDA, you can use either. `find_program_address` consumes more CUs, so `create_program_address` is preferred when the bump is available.

It's common to see bumps stored on your account struct for this reason: quick validation with `create_program_address`, or for passing as signer seeds with PDA-owned accounts.

Answer (score 5):

They serve different purposes and depends on your context you can decide which one to use or a combination of both.

`create_program_address` is for creating PDA with provided seeds and bump

#### Example

Checking PDA created from provided seeds and bump matches canonical bump PDA. Will return error if provided seed result in an invalid PDA (on-curve).

```
let (expected_pda, bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"vault"], &program_id);
let actual_pda = Pubkey::create_program_address(&[b"vault", &[provided_bump]], &program_id)?;

assert_eq!(expected_pda, actual_pda);
```

`find_program_address` is for finding canonical bump PDA

#### Example

Checking provided PDA matches canonical bump PDA

```
let (canonical_bump_pda, canonical_bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"vault"], &program_id);

assert_eq!(canonical_bump_pda, provided_pda);
```

`find_program_address` may consume a variable Compute Units due to possible additional computation needed to find an off-curve PDA. This should be aware in CUs sensitive context such as onchain program.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to consider security issues. For instance. If bump seed validation is not applied, and the bump seed is untrusted data, it can lead to Bump seed canonicalization (security issue).
**create_program_address** function will [generate](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/prelude/struct.Pubkey.html#method.create_program_address) a different PDA for the same program id if the bump seed is different and does not perform any validation on the bump seed. Meanwhile **find_program_address** [returns](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/prelude/struct.Pubkey.html#method.find_program_address) a PDA using the maximum valid bump seed.